Assign to variable file downloaded by cURL returns an error: ignored null byte in input
I try to download a file using cURL and assign it to a variable:
var=$(curl -s <urlToFile>)

it returns an error:

warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

I spend a lot time to find solution but I couldn't
edit:
I try to assign many small files to variables in background threads and from this threads save everything to one file. Order of this operation is important. Also files should be downloaded simultaneously.
edit 2:
Base64 is great. Thank you Stefan Hegny!

You can't store binary data in shell variables. They're meant for text.

Thanks for your reply. Is there some other way for saving binary files and use them later in a shell script (specially downloaded by cURL)?

Save them to files? Or use a different language than shell.

or pipe it thru base64. It depends what you continue to do with it

Please [edit] your question and add details what you want to do with the data later in yor script.

See BashFAQ/058 (Can bash handle binary data?).

Your edit does not make the question much clearer. Your question looks like an XY problem. Why don't you simply save the data as files and  concatenate the files? In a shell script you can have background processes but not threads. You can export variables from the parent to the child but not back from the child to the parent.
